# How to link header files after make install pnetcdf

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I am trying to follow the instructions after installing pnet cdf. After running the following:

```
cd pnetcdf-1.11.2
./configure --prefix=$HOME/PnetCDF --with-mpi=/usr/bin --enable-netcdf4 --enable-shared --enable-thread-safe
make -j8
make install

PATH=$HOME/PnetCDF/bin:$PATH ; export PATH
```

I get the following message:

```
PnetCDF has been successfully installed under
|          /home/mmann/PnetCDF
|
|  * PnetCDF header files have been installed in
|          /home/mmann/PnetCDF/include
| # * PnetCDF library files have been installed in
| #         /home/mmann/PnetCDF/lib
|  #* PnetCDF utility programs have been installed in
|  #        /home/mmann/PnetCDF/bin
|  *# PnetCDF man pages have been installed in
|      #    /home/mmann/PnetCDF/share/man
|
|  To compile your PnetCDF programs, please add the following to the command
|  line, so the compiler can find the PnetCDF header files:
| #     -I/home/mmann/PnetCDF/include
|
|  Add the following line to link your program to PnetCDF library:
|      -L/home/mmann/PnetCDF/lib -lpnetcdf
```

As a nube, it is unclear to me how to add these links.

Do I run the following?

```
g++ -o sms ./src/sms.o -I/home/mmann/PnetCDF/include

g++ -o sms ./src/sms.o -L/home/mmann/PnetCDF/lib -lpnetcdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of sounding pedantic, you don't link header files - you *include* header files, and *link* libraries.

If `sms` is an executable program that consists of a single translation unit whose source code is contained in a file `sms.cpp`, then you can perform both steps (compilation and linkage) in a single command

```
g++ -o sms -I/home/mmann/PnetCDF/include ./src/sms.cpp -L/home/mmann/PnetCDF/lib -lpnetcdf
```

If the program is split over many source files then it's common to split the build into separate compile and link phases, like

```
g++ -o sms.o -I/home/mmann/PnetCDF/include -c ./src/sms.cpp
g++ -o some.o -I/home/mmann/PnetCDF/include -c ./src/some.cpp
g++ -o other.o -I/home/mmann/PnetCDF/include -c ./src/sms.other
```

and then

```
g++ -o sms sms.o some.o other.o -L/home/mmann/PnetCDF/lib -lpnetcdf
```

The main advantage of doing this is that if you make a change to one of the source files, you don't need to recompile all of the others (just recompile the changed one, and relink the executable).

Comment: Ok I think I see now. sms actually came from this example of installing libcurl, but I see what I need to replace sms with now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302282/how-do-i-link-libcurl-to-my-c-program-in-linux